# Input value does not change after changeDetection() in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular2-changedetection

I use this component code:

HTML:

```html
<app-input [model]="model" field="name"></app-input>
```

TypeScript:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create-edit',
  templateUrl: './post-create-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create-edit.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PostCreateEditComponent {
  model: new Post();
}
```

In my spec.ts file:

```js
describe('PostCreateEditComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PostCreateEditComponent>;
  let component: PostCreateEditComponent;
  const datas = POSTS_CREATE_EDIT_DATASET;
  const model: PostInterface = new Post([datas[0]);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...],
      providers: [...],
      declarations: [PostCreateEditComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostCreateEditComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
      component.model = model;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });

  describe('general', () => {
    it('create-edit component test', () => {
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const container = context.debugElement
          .queryAll(By.css(`app-input[field="name"]`));
        const input = container[0].queryAll(By.css(context.input.type));

        expect(input[0].nativeElement.value).toEqual(model.name);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And it says `Error: "name" input element: Expected 'First post title' to equal ''.`

I don't understand why doesn't changed the input field's value after call `changeDetection()`.

How can I solve this issue? What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is backwards from what you think it is. Jasmine assertions give the "found" value first and the expected value second. It's expecting `''` but finding `'First post title'`.

I think. Jasmine assertion responses always get me mixed up ^^

Comment: This isn't the answer at all, what on earth... I have the same issue. My textbox is supposed to be `'First post title'`, but it's not being populated. How do I get it to be populated?